# Offline Interactive Genome Map

Tags: genome

I use the CGView Server for constructing circular genome maps. It is really a convenient tool for me to explore circular genome maps because it's interactive. I can search a certain region and it can automatically hover to that region. However, the job running on CGView Server will be deleted after 7 days. Are there any alternatives to CGView Server? Preferably something that's offline so I can save it for longer than 7 days. I've checked the website on CGView, but I think the java package for CGView is not interactive. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SnapGene Viewer: https://www.snapgene.com/features/

MacVector: https://macvector.com/

ApE: https://jorgensen.biology.utah.edu/wayned/ape/

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Unipro Ugene and Snapgene Viewer (not for circular genomes, but they both have the option).

Snapgene Viewer is more user-friendly, but I think Ugene might have more tools that are free (if you want to copy-paste pieces of DNA, for instance, you can't do that in Snapgene Viewer, it would require the paid or demo version of Snapgene)